# How do I remove words in one list from another list (Set operation)

Tags: set, livecode

I have a list of word forms produced from a text. This list includes proper names (e.g. John, Mary, Edinburgh). In another field I have a list of proper names. I want to get a list of all word forms without the proper names.

I actually need 
    `allWordForms MINUS properNames`

Arrays may be used like sets. But we only have the set operations `Union` and `Intersect`.

The script so far

```
on mouseUp
   put field "allWordForms" into tWordForms
   split tWordForms by return
   -- tWordForms is now an array

   put field "properNames" into tProperNames
   split tProperNames by return
   -- tProperNames is now an array

   -- .....
   repeat  
   -- .....
   -- .....
   end repeat

   combine tWordForms using return

   put tWordForms into field "wordFormsWithoutProperNames"

end mouseUp
```

How does the repeat loop look like?

And here is an example.

The field "allWordForms" contains

```
Mary
and
John
came
yesterday
They
want
to
move
from
Maryland
to
Petersbourough
```

`

The field "properNames" contains

```
John
Mary
Maryland
Peter
Petersbourough
```

The desired result is to have a copy of the list `allWordForms` with the proper names removed.

```
and
came
yesterday
They
want
to
move
from
to
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution;

```
on mouseUp
   put field "allWordForms" into tWordForms
   put field "properNames" into tProperNames

   # replace proper names
   repeat for each line tProperName in tProperNames
      replace tProperName with empty in tWordForms
   end repeat

   # remove blank lines
   replace LF & LF with LF in tWordForms   

   put tWordForms into field "wordFormsWithoutProperNames"
end mouseUp
```

another solution taking your extra info into account;

```
on mouseUp
   put field "allWordForms" & LF into tWordForms
   put field "properNames" into tProperNames

   repeat for each line tProperName in tProperNames
      replace tProperName & LF with empty in tWordForms
   end repeat

   put tWordForms into field "wordFormsWithoutProperNames"
end mouseUp
```

Comment: I added an example to the question. Your solution gives as result the following strings (including an empty one at the beginning) `and
came
yesterday
They
want
to
move
from
land
to
sbourough`. The words `Maryland` and `Petersborough` are chopped which is not the intended result. I want to make sure that it  works with wordforms as a whole. This is why I was asking for the repeat loop and suggested to go for arrays. Arrays support the set operations `Union` and `Intersect`. I am looking for the livecode syntax  to implement  `tAllWordForms minus tProperNames`.

Comment: There's no built in array function to achieve your goal, but the second example works as required with your data.

Comment: The second solution works fine. I have tested it on Linux. As it uses LF. Does it work on Windows as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **filter *container* without *pattern*** function:

```
put field "allWordsForms" into tResult
repeat for each line aLine in field "ProperNames"
   filter tResult without aLine
end repeat
put tResult into field "wordFormsWithoutProperNames"
```